# ARKit: Occlude everything in a plane except reference image

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have an image reference that is triggering an experience on ARKit2, and I want to create an occlusion plane that covers everything around my trigger, except the trigger itself. Representatively, it is something like this (placed the image below the plane to show better, but it is in reality on the same level):

[image: Need to create the occlusion plane shown on the top]

As of now, I have no issue with making an occlusion on a regular shape like so:

```
func setOcclusionMaterial() {

    let occlusionPlane = SCNPlane(width: imageReference!.physicalSize.width, height: imageReference!.physicalSize.height)

    let holdout = SCNMaterial()
    holdout.isDoubleSided = true
    holdout.diffuse.contents = CIColor.black
    holdout.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask(rawValue: 0)
    occlusionPlane.firstMaterial? = holdout

    let occlusionNode = SCNNode()
    occlusionNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    occlusionNode.geometry = occlusionPlane
    node!.addChildNode(occlusionNode)

}
```

However, I'm not sure how I could create a plane that excludes the image area (a circle).

What I'm trying to do is to place a 3D element that appears to be below my trigger but only visible if seen top-down or with a slight angle.

Hope this is clear enough and thanks for your help if you have any ideas.

Comment: Is your trigger always rectangular? If so, try to build your occlusion geometry from 4 smaller planes with an empty space in the centre.

Comment: No. Its in fact always circular

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not render an occlusion for me, at least not in the Playground I quickly threw together. Maybe you can create one if my answer does not actually solve your problem.

You have to options here. Either create a custom geometry, in a 3D modelling tool like blender or manual via [`SCNGeometrySource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource) but that is expansive because you will need a lot of triangles to make it work.

You can try to apply a `CALayer` as the plane's `geometry`:
Create a `CGPath` that is the rectangle with the circular cutout (or any form you'd like) and create a `CAShapeLayer` from the path.

```
var path = CGMutablePath()

path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
path.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 50, height: 50))

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
layer.path = path
layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
layer.fillRule = .evenOdd
```

I could not confirm this actually worked because your occlusion is not quite working for me.